# Does OpenCL support automatic page migration?

Tags: opencl, page-fault

In the recent iteration of CUDA, one can "allocate memory" that is accessible on both the host and the device, with transfers (faults) handled automatically by the driver.

Does OpenCL currently allow for such a feature? If so, are there any implementations that actually support it?

Comment: ALLOC_HOST_PTR flag lets driver do the allocation and do sub-copies to get the sub-step-array in line with the gpu dma engine for fast access. This fast access is done with using mapping and unmapping enqueue commands. USE_HOST_PTR leaves the work of allocation and its necessary alignment to the developer and also is fast for mapping and unmapping. Both lets device kernels directly (or automatically indirectly) acceess to RAM buffer instead of a device memory buffer.

Comment: If you are asking availability of `UVA` then from CL 2.0 has `SVM` feature.

Comment: Actually, I was asking about an equivalent of the Page Migration Engine. Which OpenCL does not appear to have.